# Unable to reverse downvote after answer undeleted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, downvotes, deleted-answers, grace-period

I noticed something rather strange just now, specifically with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39371720/3393505).

Originally, the answerer (which doesn't show in the edit history, as it happened rather quickly after posting) had misread the question and the answer given was not relevant.  I downvoted the answer and started to comment, but the answer was deleted before I could submit it.

I then answered the question, and around the same time, the deleted answer was undeleted with edits made to it that made the answer valid.

I tried to remove my downvote and give an upvote, but I got the timeout error instead:

> You last voted on this answer X mins ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.

The answer was modified, but while it was deleted, but it still won't let me reverse it.

Comment: That's probably because the answer was edited during the grace period. The [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39371720/revisions) shows that the post was undeleted 4 minutes after posting.

Comment: Do a bogus edit to lift the restriction and then remove the down vote.  It should not be a habit but it is one ways to reverse a mistake/correct something after it has been changed.

Comment: @NathanOliver That did the trick - I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: No problem.  It is a "hack" but sometimes it is worth it.  I've done it from time to time to fix a down vote after the user fixes the answer and I missed the window.

Comment: @Gothdo That makes sense - I thought it might have had something to do with it being modified whilst in a deleted state.  But the modification in the grace period also makes sense.

Comment: Related: [Vote can't be changed if answer is edited too quickly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78442/vote-cant-be-changed-if-answer-is-edited-too-quickly)

Comment: @animuson shouldn't deletion create a revision, which would allow the user to change its vote?

Comment: @Braiam Deletion is not a revision, it's just a history event in the same class as closing/reopening and protecting a question. They're also displayed differently in the revision history to indicate that. The vote locking mechanism only looks at actual edits to the post, not everything else that can occur on a post.